# wolfssl SendClientKeyExchange failed

Tags: ssl, wolfssl

I ported wolfssl to Liteos and an error occurred while running:

```
wolfSSL error occurred, error = 111 line:11221 file:src/ssl.c
```

error = -111, mp_read error state

I Trace the underlying code to find the location of the error:

```
        case FIRST_REPLY_FIRST :
    #ifdef WOLFSSL_TLS13
    printf("into WOLFSSL_TLS13 ..\n");
        if (ssl->options.tls1_3)
            return wolfSSL_connect_TLSv13(ssl);
    #endif
        if (!ssl->options.resuming) {
            if ( (ssl->error = SendClientKeyExchange(ssl)) != 0) {
                WOLFSSL_ERROR(ssl->error);  //Error occurred !!
                return WOLFSSL_FATAL_ERROR;
            }
            WOLFSSL_MSG("sent: client key exchange");
        }

        ssl->options.connectState = FIRST_REPLY_SECOND;
        WOLFSSL_MSG("connect state: FIRST_REPLY_SECOND");
        FALL_THROUGH;
```

The wolfssl version is 4.2.0-stable

I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason that public key operations fail is due to the stack and/or heap not being set high enough. The [wolfSSL Porting Guide](https://www.wolfssl.com/docs/porting-guide/) has a section on memory requirements. Can you double check your available memory in your project?